# Making the html table responsive without using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design

How to we make the HTML table to responsive without using bootstrap or JQuery, it has more than eight-column.

I'm Using Percentage for each column even its not coming responsive when we increase the text

Scroll coming at the bottom. how to avoid scroll, I don't want to use the Unorder list or div elements

```css
body{
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:12px
    }
    .text-to-right {
        text-align: right;
      }
      .text-to-left {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 1rem;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-left: 1px solid #f3f1f1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f1f1fa;
        border-spacing: 0;
      }
      .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
      .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
      .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td,
      .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
      .table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
      .table-bordered > thead > tr > th {
        border-left: 1px solid #f3f1f1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d2cecefa;
        /*box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(241, 230, 230, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(247, 245, 245, 0.12);*/
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 #f3f1f1,0 1px 1px 0 #f3f1f1;
      }
      .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:first-child,
      .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:first-child,
      .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:first-child,
      .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:first-child,
      .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:first-child,
      .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:first-child {
        border-left-width: 0;
      }
      .table-bordered tbody tr td:last-child,.table-bordered thead tr th:last-child {  
        border-right: 1px solid #f3f1f1;;
      }
      .table-bordered > thead > th:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid #f3f1f1;
      }
      th {
        padding: 1rem 0;
        background: #192b4b;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        font-weight: normal;
        border-left: 1px solid #f3f1f1;
      }
      td {
        padding: 1rem;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        color: #6b5e5e;
      }
      
      .table-bright-data {
        color: #007dc5;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;
      }
```

```html
   
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="05%">
                   S.No
                </th>
                <th class="text-to-left" width="23%">Name</th>
                <th width="10%">Code</th>
                <th width="12%">Type</th>
                <th width="10%"> Profile</th>
                <th width="13%">Time</th>
                <th width="10%">Size</th>
                <th width="11%">Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="text-to-left table-bright-data">Responsive layout</td>
                <td class="text-to-left">LDHSNSJ734674</td>
                <td class="text-to-left">Fixed Interest </td>
                <td class="text-to-left">high </td>
                <td class="text-to-right">No minimum </td>
                <td class="text-to-right">0 </td>
                <td class="text-to-right">05-Dec-2001 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">
                    2
                </td>
                <td class="text-to-left table-bright-data">Responsive layout</td>
                <td class="text-to-left">DHEYE933</td>
                <td class="text-to-left">Responsive layout </td>
                <td class="text-to-left"> </td>
                <td class="text-to-right">No minimum </td>
                <td class="text-to-right">0 </td>
                <td class="text-to-right">05-Dec-2001 </td>
            </tr>       
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: before this gets closed.. use bootstrap. google it.

Comment: I don't want use bootstrap.

Comment: then drop your code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collapse a table like this

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .collapse {
        display: block;
    }}
```

HTML

```
<td class="collapse">
  Content
</td>
<td class="collapse">
  Content
</td>
```

I would add multiple classes with different `@media (max-width: xxx)` so they don't collapse all at once. How you want to collapse them, and in what order you should figur out yourself.
You can look over here https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/ if you got any more questions.

Personally I like using div over tables, e.g: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/